# intergrating database for android app

Tags: android, database

Is there a way to integrate a mobile database for your app? If so, is it extremely hard? I have not yet started on any code, I just would like to know how it can be done and the measures that encompasses such a desire to integrate a database for the android app.

I would like to do the following:
A user would like to search for a restaurant nearby...they think they know the name of the restaurant, so they begin typing letters. If they type a U, all the restaurants that start with a "U" will show up. Once they find the restaurant they are looking for, they click on it and get the information.

Can this be done?
Thank you.

Comment: You mean database hosted on remote server (or) ship pre-created database with your app?

Comment: this is where I think it becomes complicated...we are part of this company who controls the database. for example, we use their search engine to retrieve results that are stored on their server. so I am unsure how I would even take this step in taking what results are given to our customers...delivered to our app. 

does that make any sense?

Comment: for example, when a customer would like to search for an item, let's say a movie, the results are coming from their server...not ours. so we do not control the search results or anything.

Comment: That is fine, so what you are saying is, you need to invoke service provided by some third party right?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are referring to? I am new to all of this, so I need it explained in mroe detail. Please and thank you.

Comment: AFAIK, this is how it works, company who have database need to give you a URL which takes your search term as parameter and returns either XML (or) Json as response. You need to invoke that url by appending your search terms (entered by user) with help HTTPClient API from android, which return corresponding results either XML (or) Json. If Json response you can use android JSonObject api to parse the response. If XML response, you need to use SAX/DOM parsers.

Comment: awesome! thank you so much! you are truly awesome - you gave me what I was looking for...now for the ultimate test...to see if I can pull through. thanks again! :) I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad it helped you. If you are happy with answer, accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this is how it works, company who have database need to give you a URL which takes your search term as parameter and returns either XML (or) Json as response. You need to invoke that url by appending your search terms (entered by user) with help HTTPClient API from android, which return corresponding results either XML (or) Json. If Json response you can use android JSonObject api to parse the response. If XML response, you need to use SAX/DOM parsers.